# i am not able to render my animation

Tags: rendering, animation

im new to blender, it took a week for me to design a terrain and put a road on it , later design car with rotation of wheels and everything.

my basic scene setup was, a moving car on road in desert terrain .

My PC configuration is 8gb ram ,
Intel (r) core TM i7-7500u CPU @ 2.70GHZ 2.90GHZ
64- bit

The car i designed and terrain i designed have a lot of nodes, textures and stuff.

im working since a week with out sleep i need help guys.

when i try to render the animation, the screen changes to render screen and its empty[image][image]

Comment: It is impossible to tell whats wrong, even whether something is wrong at all from these screenshots. You could increase the chance of getting help by adding more information, for example uploading the not-working file (or a file with the exact same problem) to https://blender.stackexchange.com/. Then edit the question and paste the generated link into it.

Comment: thanks, im uploading the file, is my configuration god enough ?

Comment: cause i put also put nurbs path where the car has to follow and camera has to follow

Comment: The anim is all fine in the 3d viewport ?

Comment: Yes, it's very quick from 0 to 32 , but it's good enough fast

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qMvd9--slqBmlKbhirniVPLgNvcEMnLD i have attavhed blender file above

Comment: hello Sreekar, we don't have free access to your file

Comment: what you need to do is a composite course